# Generating results in a search box in AngularJS and Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I'm looking to display results in a navigation bar.

HTML

```
<input type="text" ng-model="result" min-length="2" typeahead="institution.id as institution.name for institution in institutions($viewValue)" style="display:block" placeholder="Search">
```

JS

```
$scope.institutions = function(institution) {
    return $institutions, {
        query: institutions
    }
        .then(function(response) {
            return limitToFilter(response.data, 15);
        });
};
```

Here's the error I get in the console.

[image: Console Error]

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.institutions = function(institution) {
    return{ $institutions, {
        query: institutions
    }
        .then(function(response) {
            return limitToFilter(response.data, 15);
        });
}
};
```